# Multiple restart during boot + bios reset

Tags: bios, computer-building

I recently built a computer but am running into an issue. Everytime I start the computer, it restarts itself during boot multiple times and when it finally comes up properly, BIOS did reset to default settings.

It kinda feels like it is loosing its power, so I exchanged the power supply with my own one which worked for the last year and still works, but that didn't change anything, still the same.
Because of the BIOS reset I thought of the battery, but exchanging this one with a new one also didn't help.
Removing the GPU didn't change a thing.
Also, all of this is quite suspicious, cause I just freshly bought everything, and it's by far not the first time I'm building a computer. But now I'm stuck.

Also here are the specs:

- Processor: i3-8350k
- Motherboard: Gigabyte B360 HD3
- RAM: G.skill Ripjaws V 2x 4GB on 2400
- Power Supply: Corsaier CX600
- GPU: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1060 6GB

Comment: Is there the same multi-reboot if you reboot the PC vai OS's "Start - Reboot" command?

Comment: @Akina There is no OS yet, i havent even gotten so far.